# The suggested edit appears to be spam

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, spam

Look at the linked [suggested edit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/5512) by [this user](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/2571/gertschi).

The user essentially changed a rotted link (404) to what appears to me to be a commercial site that has nothing to do with the previously linked document.

Since the user doesn't have any posts on programmers, I felt this was the only way to bring attention to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if Oded had looked carefully at the content of the link. That page has a button that links to the previous PDF that is now 404.

It was not SPAM and it isn't a "bad edit". The domain was the exact same as the one that replaced it.

http://www.maestrodev.com/support/ has the link to the PDF that went 404.

Personally I think the support page is a better link than a direct link to the PDF anyway, as it probably won't change.

Comment: Then why not link directly to the PDF?

Comment: how do I know, but it only took me 2 seconds to figure their intention, which was well intended.

Comment: You are a better man than I am... I saw a commercial support page and assumed the worst.

Comment: if you look at the 404 link and the one that they replaced it with, the DOMAIN is exactly the same, then I saw the link to the book! 2 seconds. :-(

Answer (score 3):

There's not a lot we (as moderators) can do other than reject the edits as they appear. Suspending the user would be overkill for one bad edit, however if the behaviour persisted then it might be in order.

A history of bad suggested edits will also result in a ban from suggesting edits so rejection is exactly the right thing to do in these circumstances.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and let the user know I was flagging it.